# Partial view load with layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

When I tried to load my partial view inside the modal. it loads with layout page also. But I didn't put my layout page to my partial view. Why layout page called automatically to my partial view I cannot find the layout page called in in partial view.

This is my partial view code

```
@model Mvc.Models.Company

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Company</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.URL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.URL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.URL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tstamp, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tstamp, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tstamp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsDeleted, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsDeleted)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsDeleted, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

This is my Controller code

```
public ActionResult _Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult _Create([Bind(Include = "CompanyID,Name,Address,PhoneNumber,URL,Email,Active")] Company company)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Companies.Add(company);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(company);
        }
```

Calling Create page from the Index page

```
<button id="createCompanyButton" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Create Company</button>

<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="createCompanyFormModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Default Modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="createCompanyFormModalbody" class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click','#createCompanyButton', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Companies/_Create',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#createCompanyFormModalbody').html(data);
                    $('#createCompanyFormModal').modal('show');
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("There is some problem in the service!");
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try returning PartialView() instead of View()

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in your action, you are returning partial view result.

try this, I hope this will work for you!

```
public ActionResult _Create()
        {
            return PartialView("_nameOfPartial");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult _Create([Bind(Include = "CompanyID,Name,Address,PhoneNumber,URL,Email,Active")] Company company)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Companies.Add(company);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return PartialView("_NameOfPatial", company);
        }
```

if you are showing partial list on your index then you should return like this

```
        public ActionResult Index(PrintingListSearchFilter filter)
        {
              //your model logic 

            return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? PartialView("_yourListPartialView", model) : 
                   View("Index", model) as ActionResult;
        }
```